# Is it normal to keep changing research objectives in PhD?

Tags: computer-science

During my first year, my supervisor advised me to have four objectives that lead to four contributions to the research.

Throughout the journey, until I'm now on my final year (in computer science), I realize myself to keep changing my objectives as the needs of the research keep evolving. And, as the research has evolved, some objectives do not make any sense due to some reasons such as it's not so significant, too simple, and redundant.

My supervisor is always asking how many of objectives (out of four) that I have achieved so far? I can't really answer as it has changed from my first to second, to third a year.

So my question is, is it normal if I keep changing my objectives without sticking the those I outlined during my first year? And, it is still okay to change objectives when I'm now in my final year?

Comment: Have you been discussing the shifts in your objectives with your supervisor?

Comment: This will depend a lot on how big those changes were and how big they seem to your supervisor. I think it may be useful, both for you and for your supervisor, if you make a chart showing how your objectives have evolved, along with the reasons for those changes.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan not yet

Comment: @AndreasBlass My supervisor is not really contributing to my research. So, most of the things I decided on my self. I dilemma arose when I'm not sure whether the objectives can be considered as objectives for a PhD or not and I don't feel good about it. Then, I re-write them to fir with the current progress of my research

Comment: @Aqee I don't think my experience is relevant, because each change in direction during my PhD research was discussed with my advisor as it was happening. I wanted his input on appropriateness of each new direction.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I'm facing the problem of unsupportive supervisor. So, I decided many things by myself. The direction doesn't change actually. Still the same main aim. But, the objectives involve throughout the way

Comment: Relevant comic: [PhD: Your plan vs. reality](https://www.facebook.com/NeuroNewsResearch/photos/your-plan-versus-reality-phd/2081510905200990/)

Comment: Can you provide more information on what an "objective" is in this context? For example, is an objective like "mentor a student" or "publish x papers", or is it more like "contribute to this specific area" or "improve this specific method"?

Comment: @kjacks21it is more like "contribute to this specific area"

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is, is it normal if I keep changing my objectives without sticking the those I outlined during my first year?

Yes.  It would be unusual if you did not improve your objectives.  Improved objectives is a symptom of improved research.

> And, it is still okay to change objectives when I'm now in my final year?

It's not okay to start your research over from scratch when you do not have enough time to complete new research.  It is okay to discover that your existing efforts achieved goals you didn't think of when you started (but scientists should avoid data dredging).  In other words, it depends on the details.

Comment: I'm not starting the research over. Just in some cases, the objective is not relevant. I removed that one and replaced withanother one. But still, in the same direction.

Comment: BTW, what is "hypothesis mining"?

Comment: "hypothesis mining" is the same as "data dredging" that I thought was standard but Google says I am wrong.

Comment: What is your comment about my response above?

Comment: I stick to my answer:  It depends on the details.

Comment: Said differently: Don't worry if you don't hit your intended target.  Good research is often the result of painting a new target around the arrow, wherever it landed, and then saying "Look at what I hit!"